# Connect two Existing Web parts available in SharePoint Portal Server 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts, kpi

We are creating a BI dashboard using SharePoint Portal Server 2007 and have following requirements and could you please tell us it is possible to without creating custom web parts.
1)
When user clicks on a row in list web part, is it possible to refresh another web part based on the selection in first web part. 
2)
Can we connect KPI and KPI detailed webpart so that when your cliecks on measure (ex: Gross Margin%) then KPI detailed refreshed with data based on selection (ex: Details about Gross Margin calculation in KPI detailed web part)

Thanks
Bipin

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, though it depends on the web parts you are using. In general, if something shows up under connections on the web part menu you will be able to connect the web parts.